# Child component unable to render because Context API comes out as undefined for first render of Child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to get a child component to render only when the Context API state that I set up is fully mounted. The Parent component is grabbing from the server and setting the state based on the information received. I keep getting Undefined in the first render, then it re-renders and it comes out as an Array. I want only to render this component so the Child may render it's component without any errors. I've attempted to use the UseEffect but I don't understand it that well..

Here is the Child Component...

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./bathoneform.module.css";
import Ratings from "../Ratings";
import {
  BathOneFormContext,
  FormQuestionsContext,
} from "../../Store";

function BathOneForm() {
  const [formQuestions, setFormQuestions] = useContext(FormQuestionsContext);
  const [bathOneFormAnswers, setBathOneFormAnswers] = useContext(
    BathOneFormContext
  );
  //setting the array
  const array = formQuestions.bathone;
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setBathOneFormAnswers((state) => ({ ...state, [name]: value }));
  };
  console.log(formQuestions);
  return (
    <div>
      <form
        className={styles["BathroomOneFormWrapper"]}
        id="bathroom-one-form"
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        {array.map((object, index) => {
          return (
            <div className={styles["CheckboxWrapper"]} key={index}>
              <h5>{object}</h5>
              <Ratings
                Question={object}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BathOneForm;
```

Here is the code from Parent Component where I grab from the server...

```
export default function MoveInForm({ Apartment }) {
  const [formQuestions, setFormQuestions] = useContext(FormQuestionsContext);
  const [state, setState] = useContext(FormSectionsContext);
  const getData = async () => {
    const apartmentName = Apartment.toLowerCase();
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
    headers.append("Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    const response = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/${apartmentName}`,
      headers
    );

    await setFormQuestions(response.data[0].bathone);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
```

App.js....

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router- 
dom";
import styles from "./App.module.css";
import DocumentTitle from "react-document-title";
import MoveInForm from "./pages/MoveInForm";
import NoMatch from "./components/NoMatch";
import Store from "./Store";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  //Title Case
  String.prototype.toProperCase = function () {
    return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
      return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
  };

  const renderMoveIn = (routerProps) => {
    const Name = routerProps.match.params.apartment.toLowerCase();
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
    headers.append("Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/${Name}`, headers)
      .then((res) => {
        setState(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    const Apartment = apartmentName.toProperCase();
    return state ? <MoveInForm Apartment={Apartment} /> : <NoMatch />;
  };
  return (
    <DocumentTitle title="Move-In Inspection">
      <Store>
        <Router>
          <div className={styles["App"]}>
            <Switch>
              <Route
                path="/:apartment"
                render={(routerProps) => renderMoveIn(routerProps)}
              />
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Store>
    </DocumentTitle>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you add the code to show how `BathOneForm()` and `MoveInForm()` are called?

Comment: Adding it now....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the DOM will render first, before the `promise` is `resolved` or `fulfilled`. As the `promise` runs on the network thread, it will queue the result callback in the `micro task` thread, which will run after the DOM has completed its first render.

What you can do is

1. Set a `isLoading` state in the component, and set it to `true` for the initial value. And set it to `false` after the `promise` resolves.
2. Create an `if` condition in the component to load an empty `div` if the array is empty.